# Weird issue with google maps. It shows wrong tiles

Tags: google-maps-api-3

It seems google maps stopped working properly a couple of hours ago. It displays the wrong tiles at the wrong coordinates. I've tried accessing my applications from different physical locations and tried different maps, but nothing helps. 
Strange thing is.. it worked perfectly fine till last night and nothing changed in my source.

I'm also experiencing this issue in the basic example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple and I'm curious if if works for anyone else.

I wonder if there is some (global) issue or if I somehow missed an important update? I can't find anything relevant using Google, so I hope someone here can help me out.

By the way.. https://maps.google.com works fine.

Kind regards,

Bart

Comment: Can you elaborate on what's happening? Have you checked that your GPS module is returning proper coordinates? Do you have any options enabled for geo-location based on WiFi access points?

Comment: @EWit: It looks like the wrong tiles are being displayed over the right coordinates. All my custom markers show up on the correct location in relation to each other and googles auto complete search box shows up the relevant results for my area. It's just the tiles that are wrong (both map and satellite). It's not my application. It also happens to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple . Happens on different computers on different geographical locations (different offices). No GPS module involved.

Comment: A new version of the API was pushed recently.  It is possible you are seeing an effect of that.  Have you done a full refresh and/or flushed your cache?  BTW - I don't see a problem with the example you linked (unless I need to do something to see it, I see a map of Australia).

Comment: It may be a coincidence but with my maps is happening something similar without any code change. Is this what is happening to you too? http://postimg.org/image/97i3b9lsp/. The examples in google.com are working properly, but in localhost I have cleared the cache and tested with several browsers and everything stays the same. I am going to investigate the root cause and provide a proper reduced case to be sure what this is.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, here's a screenie: http://i.imgur.com/JW3B7Os.jpg It's weird that the same tile is being displayed in @FagnerBrack example.

Comment: exactly! i'm seeing this http://postimg.org/image/97i3b9lsp/

Comment: By the way.. clearing cache etc.. even trying an completely new clean browser doesn't make any difference at all.

Comment: Yes, it solved here too. It looks like some Google intern managed to break Google Maps and the code went to production for a few hours hahaha.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue has gone away. All of a sudden a simple map reload (not even clearing the cache) makes the default map load properly.

I still have no idea what happened, but at least I'm glad it's working again.

Comment: Yes, it solved here too. It looks like some Google intern managed to break Google Maps and the code went to production for a few hours hahaha.

Comment: Really strange, I'm working with GMaps API from 5 hours, and I don't have any problem...

Comment: It seems to be a problem just for specific users, like the product of some A/B testing failure. Only someone from Google to clear up exactly what happened. Pretty crazy huh? That never happened to me.

Comment: Issue still continues here, sadly

Comment: It wasn't fixed for me last time I checkd

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps For Business support just let me know that this issue should be fixed now.

It was a problem with "tile caching", they said.

Although it is still broken for someone I am working with